# Run "Instant Run" from command line

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, instant-run

I'm running my Android app from Android Studio, and Instant Run kicks in, which is great. I want to run the exact same thing from the command-line.

In Android Studio's *Event Log*, I see

```
22:00:28 Executing tasks: [:app:incrementalDevDebugSupportDex]
22:00:48 Gradle build finished in 20s 286ms
22:00:51 Instant Run applied code changes and restarted the current Activity.
```

So, I expected I would be able to run that task from the command line: `./gradlew :app:incrementalDevDebugSupportDex`. However, it's not found:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'incrementalDevDebugSupportDex' not found in project ':app'.
```

Is there a way to run with Instant Run from the command line?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is currently not possible to use instant run outside of Android Studio. This was mentioned at the Android Dev Summit, but I can't recall exactly in which talk that was.

Comment: well that's a letdown. i did exactly what OP did. why would they tie this functionality to an IDE...

Comment: I believe it was mentioned in the [fireside chat](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BxjlT11MDW4) but I could track down the timestamp quickly

Answer (score 3):

You can run instant-run from command line like this:

```
./gradlew clean :sample-app:assembleDebug -Pandroid.optional.compilation=INSTANT_DEV -Pandroid.injected.build.api=24
```

Answer (score 1):

As of now it is possible.  You can run the below command to make an instant run :

```
./gradlew :app:incremental"buildvarientname"DebugJavaCompilationSafeguard
```

You can add the same in gradle task also by adding `incremental"buildvarientname"DebugJavaCompilationSafeguard` inside the task on the run configuration window,

Comment: why don't I see these tasks when running `./gradlew :app:tasks` ?

Comment: hmmm i dont see it in the tasks  either.